# Finding an explicit smooth atlas for $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

It is a standard exercise to show that 
$(GL_n(\mathbb{R}), \tau, D)$ is a smooth manifold, where

$$\tau = \{\phi^{-1} (U) \subseteq GL_n (\mathbb{R}) | U\in \mathbb{R}^{n^2} is \quad open, \phi: GL_n(\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}^{n^2} \quad \text{s.t $\phi$ sends the entries of a matrix to an $n^2$-tuple with the same entries} \},$$
and
$$D = \{f\circ\phi:GL_n (\mathbb{R})\to \mathbb{R}^k | f: V\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n^2}\to \mathbb{R}^k \text{is a a differentiable map in the usual sense}\}.$$

However, I would like to find a smooth atlas for this smooth manifold $(GL_n(\mathbb{R}), \tau, D)$ **explicitly**, i.e explicitly smooth coordinate patches that they cover the whole set altogether.

Comment: You have that explicit single-chart atlas that covers the entire $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$.  Transition functions are trivial.

Comment: $\{({\rm GL}(n,\Bbb R), \phi)\}$ is a perfectly good atlas.

Comment: @IvoTerek Yes, apparently so (I couldn't noticed it until user10354138's comment :) )

Comment: Otherwise (from the LU decomposition) with $N$ the upper triangular matrices with $1$ on the diagonal and $D$ the diagonal matrices then $GL_n(\Bbb{R}) = N^\top D N$ and $D = (\Bbb{R}^*)^n\cong \{ \pm 1\}^n \times \exp(\Bbb{R}^n)$ which makes clear you need $2^n$ charts $\Bbb{R}^{n^2}\to GL_n(\Bbb{R})$

Comment: @reuns I really have no idea what you are trying to tell; can you be more explicity in your argument.

Comment: Pick two matrices $u,v \in N\cong \Bbb{R^{n(n-1)/2}}$ and one $d \in D\cong(\Bbb{R}^*)^n$ and send them to $u^\top d v \in GL_n(\Bbb{R})$, the map $(u,d,v) \to u^\top d v $ is a smooth chart $\Bbb{R^{n(n-1)/2}} \times (\Bbb{R}^*)^n \times \Bbb{R^{n(n-1)/2}} \to GL_n(\Bbb{R})$ (it is easily seen to be injective, the LU decomposition shows it is surjective, and it is smooth, thus its directional derivatives never vanish, so it has smooth local inverses, they glue together to give smooth global inverses)

Comment: @reuns I see; thanks for the comment. However, I am still not able to understand the purpose of the comment; What is the importance of that map to this question ? I'm just asking this to understand.

Comment: Try with $GL_2$ and $SL_2$, define the charts explicitly and see what information you get from them.